# How to respond a petition of user in shiny dashboard when this is running

Tags: r, shiny, shinydashboard

I have done a function that returns some information of a web page using its API. I want to put this inside of my Dashboard, so that the user can put the "ID"(RUC) inside of the dashboard an this respond with the value of the API.

MY API function is this:

```
sunat<- function(x){
  RUC_str<-as.character(x)
  url1<-paste("https://api.sunat.cloud/ruc/",RUC_str,sep = "", collapse = NULL)
  url1
  res<- GET(url1)
  data<-fromJSON(content(res, type="text", encoding = "UTF-8"))
  razon_social<-data[["razon_social"]]
  empleados<-data[["empleados"]]       
  fecha_inscripcion<-data[["fecha_inscripcion"]]
  representante_legal<-data[["representante_legal"]]  
  representante_legal_name<-representante_legal[[1]][["nombre"]]  
  trabajadores_agosto<-empleados[["2020-08"]][["trabajadores"]]
  x <- data.frame("Nombre de la empresa"=razon_social, "Nombre del representante legal(agosto)" = representante_legal_name,
                  "Trabajadores(agosto-2020)" = trabajadores_agosto,"fecha de inscripci?n"=fecha_inscripcion)
  
  
}

prove<-sunat(20100154057)
```

So, I want to use this function when my Dasboard is running, so that the user can search the API information. I tried some like this (in a simplified version). Obiously It doesn't work, but shows my doubt:

```
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)



ui <- dashboardPage(
  dashboardHeader(),
  dashboardSidebar(textInput(inputId="text_input", "RUC", value=sunat(inputId))),
  dashboardBody()
)
       
        
server<- function(input, output) {}


shinyApp(ui,server)
```

Thanks in advance